# Mysql query with limited results

Tags: mysql, limit

in a table I have a field: position that must be 1, 2 or 3.I need extract all record but 
if position is 1 I need record from 2 to last
if position is 2 I need record from 2 to last
if position is 3 I need record from 13 to last
I try so but not work and I'm not sure that this is the right way:

```
(
SELECT * FROM articoli
WHERE posizione = 1  
ORDER BY datapubb DESC 
LIMIT 2 , 5000
)

UNION

(
SELECT * FROM articoli
WHERE posizione = 2  
ORDER BY datapubb DESC 
LIMIT 3 , 5000
)

UNION

(
SELECT * FROM articoli
WHERE posizione = 3
ORDER BY datapubb DESC 
LIMIT 13 , 5000
)
```

Comment: Limit 2,5000 - gives result from 3rd row, o being first row

Answer (score 0):

I have solved so:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        idarticoli, titolo, posizione, pubblicato, datapubb
    FROM
        jaretene_news.articoli
    WHERE
        posizione = 1 AND pubblicato = 1
    LIMIT 1 , 5840) AS q 
UNION ALL SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        idarticoli, titolo, posizione, pubblicato, datapubb
    FROM
        jaretene_news.articoli
    WHERE
        posizione = 2 AND pubblicato = 1
    LIMIT 3 , 5840) AS r 
UNION ALL SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        idarticoli, titolo, posizione, pubblicato, datapubb
    FROM
        jaretene_news.articoli
    WHERE
        posizione = 3 AND pubblicato = 1
    LIMIT 8 , 5840) AS s
ORDER BY datapubb DESC
```